# no USB devices or running emulators detected even developer option is turned on

Tags: android, android-studio

I have run android application on real device but suddenly now when i connect my device to my android device android studio is showing "No USB devices or running emulator detected " even debuger option is turned on

I do not know what is the problem can any one help?

Comment: which OS you are using "Windows" or "MacOS" or "Ubuntu"?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue and follow these steps and got resolved.
1. enable Developer mode in Device.
2. Go to ABD interface (With error)from the start menu . some time windows os fail to load device driver.
3. and load http://adbdriver.com/downloads/ and download driver. unzip and run.
4. now go to android studio every thing is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADB over network but your device must be rooted

1- Open your device's terminal and type;

```
su
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

2- Open the Android Studio's terminal section and type;
adb connect {your devices ip addres}:5555
for example `adb connect 192.168.1.22:5555`